# Powershell - Trying to Copy AND Move files however it keeps saying it already exists

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find any files that begin with **ADRUPD** and then copy them to first location, and then move them to second location. I can confirm the $directory paths are all correct however when I run the below, it only copies the files in to the first location and then errors with:

> "Copy-Item : Cannot overwrite the item with itself"

Code:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $directory -Filter "ADRUPD_*" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $directory2 -PassThru | Move-Item -Destination $directory1
```

Any assistance with the correct input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add `-Verbose` to `Copy-Item` and to `Move-Item`, this should help you see that the order of operation would be: `Copy From $directory To $directory2 > Move From $directory2 To $directory1 > Copy From $directory2 To $directory1 > Move From $directory2 To $directory1`. You shouldn't do this on one pipeline.

Comment: i dunno dude/dudette, but there is a step there that is unnecessary: either the move or the copy. you first copy a file to another directory, and then move that same file to a third directory. wouldn't it be easier to just copy straight to the third directory? when you are done, there wouldn't be a file on the second directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you to perform copy / moving operations in one pipeline as you're currently doing. Here is an example of how you can do it with a `foreach` loop.

**Code below does not handle file collision, if there is a file with the same name in either of the destination folders this will error out.**

```
$origin = 'origin/path'
$copyDir = 'path/to/copyDir/'
$moveDir = 'path/to/MoveDir/'

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -File -Path $origin -Filter "ADRUPD_*" -Recurse) {
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -Destination $copyDir
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -Destination $moveDir
}
```

As aside, I'm assuming you want to move the files from `$origin` to `$moveDir` since it's what's logical. On your code, when you do:

```
Copy-Item -Destination $directory2 -PassThru
```

You're passing the copied item's path through the pipeline and performing a moving operation over that file which I don't believe is what you are looking to do.

Comment: I may have accidentally left that -PassThru in there.

You are a legend....using the foreach as you mentioned above has worked exactly as i was wanting. Thanks so much for you help with this.

Comment: @maliciousoneone happy to help :)